# Authentication error for in-app purchase

Tags: android, authentication, in-app-purchase

I am trying to get a donation button working through in app purchase.  I have followed the tutorial and I keep getting "Authentication is required, you need to sign into your google account".  I am signed in and my in-app purchase ability works for other app just not mine.  I have uploaded a released signed apk to google and I believe but am not sure how to confirm that I have the same one on my phone.  I have seen one other post that is similar but with no answer.  Here is my code

```
public void donations(View e){
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if (result.isFailure() || !purchase.getSku().equals("donations") || !purchase.getDeveloperPayload().equals(100)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Purchasing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start purchase successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
                        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
                                int messageResId = R.string.donate_default;
                                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                                    messageResId = R.string.donate_success;
                                }
                                else {
                                    messageResId = R.string.donate_fail;;
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                messageResId = R.string.donate_default;
                            }
                        };
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase,mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
        }
    };
    mHelper.flagEndAsync();
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, "donations", 100, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "donation");
}
```

Comment: Figured it out, super easy.  I uploaded my apk but didn't put PUBLISH.